# Why using a SSL certificate if top websites doesn't use them?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

We've been told that:

> Certificate validity exists because one of the core features of SSL is server authentication. This allows the client (web browser) to know the identity of the server it is connecting to. Without server authentication, you would not know if you are connecting to the authentic website.

But I know a long list of top media websites that don't even bother to use HTTPS. Check that the links redirect to HTTP or give a certificate error.

- https://www.nytimes.com
- https://www.wsj.com
- https://www.imdb.com
- https://www.bbc.com
- https://www.cnn.com

Comment: The intent of your question is not clear for me: Do you ask why you should use HTTPS for your site, why some big sites don't use HTTPS, why others have a bad certificate or why you should be better than others? Please checkout also existing questions about these topics since some of these questions have answers here already.

Comment: The sites you list are sites where 100% of the content is public.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The whole is greater than the sum of its parts, so don't break down my question into simpler ones. Please post link to answer why those sites don't need server authentication.

Comment: It's not about breaking down your question, but about understanding the intent. The 'parts' could be interpreted to mean different 'sums'. It would help to understand what you are trying to get at.

Comment: @TreyBlalock the main purpose of https is to allows websites to secure authentic content to the user whether privately or publicly.

Comment: @TreyBlalock The fact that it's public doesn't mean I don't care if people see me reading it. If server logs show that I spend 95% of my time online reading about a politically volatile topic on CNN.com and AlJazeera.com, that tells you what I care about, how much I care about it, and gives you some indication of how likely I am to take some action on it.

Comment: And you'd think CNN.com would care a little more about using HTTPS, given that they published a story on how Google will penalize sites that don't use it (like themselves): http://money.cnn.com/2016/09/08/technology/google-chrome-flag-non-secure-sites/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These big sites do need to start using HTTPS and are likely in the process of switching over however they were established long before it was recommended to secure whole sites with SSL/TLS.

The process of switching from HTTP to HTTPS can be much harder for long time established websites, especially when they have a large volume of old content to sort though and have links to this content all over the web. Any visitor coming from a non-secure link would need to be redirected to the secure version of the page.

On top of this, any media content on the pages would need the URL updating to point to a secure version. Web browsers will show a Mixed Content error and have a red broken paddle-lock if a page served over HTTPS tries to load content from a non-HTTPS location.

This Mixed Content issue can also effect any Adverting Networks the site may be using as these would need to be serving Ads via HTTPS.

Wired have quite a few articles about the difficulty they had switching over to HTTPS. You can read their retrospect here - https://www.wired.com/2016/09/wired-completely-encrypted/

Rather than focusing on what others are not doing, here are a few of the benefits for your site:

- User trust. As more of the Internet is secured, users are going to start noticing when pages are not secured. This will be further enhanced as browsers get stricter and stricter on non-secured pages. [1]
- Pages on your site can not be tampered with while passing over the Internet.
- Speed improvement if your site is running on a web server that supports HTTP/2. Web browsers only support HTTP/2 when using HTTPS. [2]
- Improved Google Rankings. HTTPS sites to may get a boost in search rankings. [3]

[1] https://security.googleblog.com/2016/09/moving-towards-more-secure-web.html

[2] https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption

[3] https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS were only commonly used by banking sites and parts of websites handling secret data (e.g. the login form) just a few years ago, but now you can't watch a Youtube video without it. The aim is no longer just to protect the data user enter, but also to hide their activities from prying eyes.

Image before Facebook was pressued to use full-site HTTPS, anyone using the site on a public wifi is opening their private pages for the world to see (and anyone on the same wifi can hijack their identities because session cookies are transmitted in plain text).

This is less of a problem for the news sites you listed and indeed for most websites that only display static info. However, as soon as you start handling user-submitted content, you'll have to consider whether your users' privacy is being protected.

E.g. if your privacy policy claim that you do not disclose user info to third-parties then how could you send them in plain-text via your ISP.